# Trapping ADO Provider cannot be found error in Delphi

Tags: delphi, odbc, ado

I have an application written in Delphi that uses an iSeries ODBC connection.

There are some workstations where I do not want to install the iSeries software, and on these workstations, I won't be updating any of these databases anyway.

Is there a way I can trap when this error message is generated?  At that point, I can just set a variable like NoUpload to true and not allow the connection on the workstation.

It appears to happen before I ever attempt to even open one of the tables - just by having the ConnectionString set when the application starts fires the message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the existing ADO providers of the system with [ADODB.GetProviderNames](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.GetProviderNames)

Comment: I figured out that I had apparently left the ADOConnection.Connected as True, which is why it was automatically trying to use the connection on startup.  However, I still wanted to disable certain functions if the ADO Provider was invalid and this enabled me to do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should look for an option to check your condition without an exception being raised. So [Sir Rufo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115943/224704) is a good place to start.

Another option might be to not include the Provider in the `ConnectionString`, but set it independently via the `Provider` property at run-time (most likely only after confirming that it's supported).

However, since you mentioned you're getting an exception before you even attempt to open a table, there are a few things to check (assuming you've been setting up your components at design time):

- Have any data sets accidentally been left `Active` at design time?
- Has the Connection been left active at design time?
- Are there any options in the ConnectionString that could immediately trigger the error?

---

Failing the above you could provide a hook for application exceptions. (And really more of a last ditch effort.)

Declare a handler method using with the following signature: `TExceptionEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; E: Exception) of object;`. And assign it to `Application.OnException`. E.g.

```
procedure Handle(ASender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  if ISeriesNotInstalledError(E) then
  begin
    FNoUpload := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    Application.ShowException(E);
  end;
end;
```

**NOTE**: There are some important considerations in following this approach. Since you see this as a standard Use Case, you don't want to be bothering your users with messages. This is also much better than a localised exception handler (a common programming error) because if a caller routine triggers this error you don't want the caller to mistakenly run as if nothing went wrong; when quite clearly something did.

Comment: I did bypass an exception per Sir Rufo's suggestion.  Essentially, on FrmMain.OnCreate, I call the ADODB.GetProviderNames.  I then check for the provider and, if not found, disable all functions that would use those tables.

Comment: Oh, and yes, the ADOConnection was accidentally left active at design time, hence the error before ever trying to open a table.  That was fixed as well.